# How to reference local Cabal library from a local Cabal executable project?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have the following folder structure:

```
~/scm/my-cabal-library
~/scm/my-cabal-executable
```

Each folder contains a Cabal sandbox and Cabal project. The first is a library and the second is an executable. I'd like for the executable to use the modules from `my-cabal-library`.

The [Cabal documentation](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html) doesn't discuss how to do this.

How do I tell Cabal about the library so that it can import the modules in my executable project?

Answer (score 4):

You refer to the library simply as `my-cabal-library` in your Cabal file. You add it to your sandbox with `cabal add-source ../my-cabal-library` which will make Cabal aware of where it can get the dependency you created.

Comment: `cabal add-source` produces `cabal: unrecognised command: add-source (try --help)` on version `compiled using version 2.2.0.1 of the Cabal library`